# trouble in rearranging the data in a text file using python

Tags: python

I am working on a code that does a lot of weird things. One of those weird things is it generates a file called `combined.glm` and the content of this file looks like this:

```
object line_space {
    content;
    content;
}

object line_conf {
    content;
    content;
}
#2 more line_conf objects

object line_ug { 
    content;
    content;
}
#70 more line_ug

object nod_l {
    content;
    content;
}
#65 more nod_l
```

I want to move all the `nod_l` sections above `line_ug` section i.e., right after `line_conf` section. The way I am trying to do is something like this:

```
...
noding=open("combined.glm",'r').readlines()
combined_order=open("combined_order.glm",'w')
for ko,comblineo in enumerate(noding):
    if 'object line_space {' in comblineo:
        combined_order.writelines(noding[ko:ko+5])
for kt,comblinet in enumerate(noding):
    if 'object line_conf {' in comblinet:
        combined_order.writelines(noding[kt:kt+5])
for kr,combliner in enumerate(noding):
    if 'object nod_l {' in combliner:
        combined_order.writelines(noding[kr:kr+5])
for kf,comblinef in enumerate(noding):
    if 'object line_ug' in comblinef:
        combined_order.writelines(noding[kf:kf+5])
...
```

But it is not working (in my head, this makes sense). I have about 28 `nod_l` copied properly, then lot of `null` characters and about 16 `line_ug` then another `nod_l` and breaks. I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You should write a solid parser and an easy to use interface for it. Everything else is then a no-brainer. Take your time and put together a tiny library with some neat classes and you're done.

Comment: …or you could go the lazy route and write a regex.

Comment: If _your_ code generated that file, why don't you change _that_ code to generate the file in the order that you want? That would certainly be easier than to rearrange the file after it has been generated in the wrong order.

Comment: @tobias_k `nod_l` uses the `content` of `line_ug`, so i can not generate `nod_l` without generating `line_ug`

Comment: @tobias_k Your comment gave me a weird idea, tried and it works...

Comment: I can't help but feel there is something _weird_ about the overuse of the word "weird'... Does no one else find that _weird_?  ;)

Comment: @Eithos Just noticed actually...:p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is dirty, but it works.

```
import re

old = open("combined.glm").read()

space = re.compile("object line_space {.*?}",re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)
conf = re.compile("object line_conf {.*?}",re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)
ug = re.compile("object line_ug {.*?}",re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)
nod = re.compile("object nod_l {.*?}",re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)

all_space = space.findall(old)
all_conf = conf.findall(old)
all_ug = ug.findall(old)
all_nod = nod.findall(old)

with open("combined_order.glm","w") as f:
    for thing in all_space:
        f.write(thing + "\n\n")
    for thing in all_conf:
        f.write(thing + "\n\n")
    for thing in all_nod:
        f.write(thing + "\n\n")
    for thing in all_ug:
        f.write(thing + "\n\n")
```

Comment: I got it working by changing a couple of lines in my code actually. But I will try this and this might be helpful in another problem (in the same code) I am working on. Although, I tried this in a new console to try your section of code but it is generating a blank `combined_order.glm` file.

Comment: I don't know; when I use it with your example file, it works.

Comment: Yea it works but I solved it some other way... This answers my question though :)